# Soft Shadows: Spherical Area Light Source

Tags: c++, graphics, geometry, raytracing

I'm attempting to implement soft shadows in my raytracer. To do so, I plan to shoot multiple shadow rays from the intersection point towards the area light source. I'm aiming to use a spherical area light--this means I need to generate random points on the sphere for the direction vector of my ray (recall that ray's are specified with a origin and direction).

I've looked around for ways to generate a uniform distribution of random points on a sphere, but they seem a bit more complicated than what I'm looking for. Does anyone know of any methods for generating these points on a sphere? I believe my sphere area light source will simply be defined by its XYZ world coordinates, RGB color value, and r radius.

Thanks and I appreciate the help!

Comment: I believe you are solving the wrong problem here; you don't actually want uniform points on a sphere (which would put most of the intensity near the edge of the sphere) but rather uniform points on a the circle seen by the point.

Comment: More details regarding the above is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709332/ray-tracing-soft-shadow/31822904#31822904

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Graphics Gems III*, page 126:

```
void random_unit_vector(double v[3]) {    
    double theta = random_double(2.0 * PI);
    double x = random_double(2.0) - 1.0;
    double s = sqrt(1.0 - x * x);
    v[0] = x;
    v[1] = s * cos(theta);
    v[2] = s * sin(theta);
}
```

(This is the second of four methods given in MathWorld's [Sphere Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) article.)

ETA: If a sphere of radius *r* is centred at **O**, and **u** is a random unit vector, then a random point on the surface of the sphere is given by **O** + *r* **u**.

Comment: Where do we take into consideration the actual position of the spherical light source in world space? According to the MathWorld resource you linked, this should be for unit spheres, so the radius is 1. But what about the actual position of the sphere light source XYZ, where is that taken into consideration?

Comment: Sorry: I thought you'd find that the easy bit! See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good formulae for random distributions are found in the [Global Illumination Compendium](http://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~philip.dutre/GI/TotalCompendium.pdf). Part **4.B.** has formulae for generating points on a (hemi) sphere. It's a great reference for sampling, integration, etc.